# algorithm python3 Time efficiency

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

In Python, the top is functional and the bottom is not.
The non-functional type has a time-out and the functional type has passed. What is the difference?

The environment is a python3 environment.

```
import sys

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
arr = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

start = 0
end = max(arr)
def solution(arr, start, end):
    result = 0
    while start <= end:
        total = 0
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        for i in arr:
            if i > mid:
                total += i - mid
        if total < m:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            result = mid
            start = mid + 1
    return result

print(solution(arr, start, end))
```

```
import sys

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
arr = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

start = 0
end = max(arr)
result = 0

while start <= end:
    total = 0
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    for i in arr:
        if i > mid:
            total += i - mid
    if total < m:
        end = mid - 1
    else:
        result = mid
        start = mid + 1

print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what system you got the time out?  Also please supplement the answer with an input test case and the expected output.

Comment: This is this site. Because it is a Korean algorithm site such as Litcode, the test case is hidden. There is no difference grammatically except that it is wrapped in a function, but it is time out so I asked a question. https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/2805

Comment: The top two cases with python3 are the cases for the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the link to the corresponding [SPOJ problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/EKO/). Looks like for this particular question the limits for python 3 is pretty closely cut and your TLE is due to the I/O. (read the comments [here](http://discuss.spoj.com/t/tle-for-binary-search-python/36106)). Your algorithm looks **correct**.

As far as the discrepancy in functional call and loop is considered. I submitted both your codes to the SPOJ, both were **TLE**.

I will recommend screening the comments beneath the question for potential pitfalls for the future reference, it is really helpful.